# how to insert multiple object with nodejs and mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

How to insert multiple object with nodejs and mysql?

I have data json like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":"317",
      "stock":"200",
      "status":"y"
   },
   {
      "id":"1224",
      "stock":"400",
      "status":"y"
   }
]
```

and this is my code:

```
function create(req, res) {
  pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) return res.send(err)
    let { id, stock, status } = req.body
    let values = [{
      id: id,
      stock: stock,
      status: status
    }]
    let sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_stock SET ?'
    connection.query(sql, values, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err)
      } else {
        connection.release()
        return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({ message: 'ok', status: HttpStatus.OK })
      }
    })
  })
}
```

this code worked if data json has one object, but I want to insert multiple object with json format like data json above, how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can insert multiple rows in bulk using array of arrays, So `values` should look something like this,

```
let values = [[317, 200, 'y'], [1224, 400, 'y']];
```

Query would look something like this,

```
let sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_stock(id, stock, status) VALUES ?';
```

Then run the query using connection,

```
connection.query(sql, values, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err)
      } else {
        connection.release()
        return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({ message: 'ok', status: HttpStatus.OK })
      }
    })
```

Comment: values needs to be in an array : connection.query(sql, [values],...)

Answer (score 0):

I solved using map and promise

```
function create(req, res) {
  pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) return res.send(err)
    let promises = []
    req.body.values.map((n) => {
      promises.push(new Promise(resolve => {
        let { id, stock, status } = n
        let values = {
          id: id,
          stock: stock,
          status: 'y',
        }
        let sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_stock SET ?'
        connection.query(sql, values, (err, results) => {
          if (err) {
            return res.send(err)
          } else {
            return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({ message: 'ok', status: HttpStatus.OK })
          }
        })
      }))

      Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
        connection.release
      })
    })
  })
}
```

data json like this:

```
{
   "values":[
      {
         "id":"317",
         "stock":"200",
         "status":"y"
      },
      {
         "id":"1224",
         "stock":"400",
         "status":"y"
      }
   ]
}
```